# Has VAR been used less frequently in the 2022 World Cup than in the English Premier League?

Tags: football, officiating, world-cup, video-review

My impression is that there has been much less use of VAR in Qatar than typically is the case in Premier League matches.

Is this an accurate perception? If so, has there been a deliberate policy on the part of FIFA to minimise its use?

Comment: I find that international games usually make less use of VAR than domestic ones. Compared to previous events Qatar used the VAR pretty often. Not many calls were overturned, though.

Comment: I've pulled some data on 40 incidents in the World Cup and 120 incidents in the EPL 21-22 to compare, so, we'll see how it turns out.

Comment: Possibly this new offside system they were using ruled out a lot of VAR work?

Comment: @TheFootsie What was "the new offside system"?

Comment: @WS2 [This](https://www.fifa.com/technical/media-releases/semi-automated-offside-technology-to-be-used-at-fifa-world-cup-2022-tm). In the EPL this work is still being done manually.

Comment: @TheFootsie That's interesting. I hadn't realised they had gone to that extent, even though I saw a few of the matches. I wonder how the technology will determine whether the positionally offside player was "interfering with play"?

Comment: @WS2 I believe it is used more as a tool for the officials than something that makes the call. Pierluigi Collina - _The referees and the assistant referees are still responsible for the decision on the field of play_.